# What is new Bytef[int] in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a code snippet below, I'm not quite sure what the last line does. More specifically what's a Bytef[]?

```
FILE* read_file_handle = fopen(read_filename, "rb");
fseek(read_file_handle, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t no_bytes_to_read = ftell(read_file_handle);
Bytef* read_buffer = new Bytef[no_bytes_to_read];
```

What is the Bytef[] do? And, if anyone knows, when porting that to PHP, how would I do that?
I thought it might be an array, but such a variable has never been defined and with the *new* keyword it just wouldn't make sense.

Can anyone help?

Hosh

EDIT:
Okay so thanks to the user Default it seems to be something defined within zlib.
It's defined as `typedef Byte FAR Bytef;` in [this file on line 124](http://www.kneuro.net/cgi-bin/lxr/http/source/arch/ppc/coffboot/zlib.h?a=alpha#L124)
Anyone know what the type of Bytef is according to that?
Byte has been defined as a char (`typedef unsigned char Byte;`) and FAR has been defined: `#define FAR`
Any help?

Comment: @Default That doesn't really help much. It just lists a load of line numbers and a link to the file where `Bytef` is defined, not an explanation.

Comment: @Default, I did try Googling it, didn't really find anything, though never found such file, but it could help me get closer to the answer, as the snippet is from something based on zlib.

Comment: @jamWaffles googling bytef would have given the OP at least a hint of what it is. For instance the link I provided (one of the first google resuls) defines bytef. Although I might have misread the question and it could be related to the `new Bytef[..]`specifically..

Comment: "Did you try googling this" is not a constructive answer, because this question is one of the first results on google for this exact problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`new Bytef[no_bytes_to_read]` simply allocates an array of `Bytef` objects with a length of `no_bytes_to_read`.

If you are porting to PHP, as you say, you may want to review [PHP arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).  I'm no PHP expert, but it appears that because arrays are implemented as ordered maps, you cannot preallocate - so there *is* no direct translation of that line.

Additionally, as Default pointed out in the link in his comment, a `Bytef` (which appears to be a part of the zlib library) is just another name for a `Byte`, which is [itself just a typedef](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/cacf7f1d4e3d44d871b605da3b647f07d718623f/zconf.h#L391) for an `unsigned char`.

To address your edited question - `#define FAR` simply creates that symbol.  It does nothing in this case - the preprocessor simply strips it.  So ultimately `Bytef` is just another name for an unsigned, 8-bit byte.

Comment: Okay, do you know what the Bytef is defined as? it seems to be a typedef but not sure how it works. Please also see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

`Bytef` is a custom type, defined in one of the header files you've included. Most likely it's a typedef for `unsigned char` or `char`; however you'll need to check your includes to be sure of what it is.

Comment: It has not been included by me, but thanks to Default, it seems to be defined in the zlib library, which the code uses in a different bit. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

`new Bytef[no_bytes_to_read]` dynamically allocates an array of `no_bytes_to_read` `Bytef` objects.  As for what a `Bytef` is, it's not a standard type, so it's got to be a custom type defined somewhere in your codebase.

Answer (score 2):

`Bytef` seems to be a custom class. note that it may be anything, from a typedef to a class, it may also be a simple c-type struct, or an enum, or a #define.

basically, the code is allocating an array of `Bytef` object,  you have to look into the code to see what `Bytef` means. since it is a type, it may well be defined inside a header file included in the current file.

Answer (score 2):

It is array of `Bytef`s. Dynamic allocation of arrays happens using `operator new[]` in C++. And `read_buffer` is pointer to it's first element.

Answer (score 2):

```
Bytef* read_buffer = new Bytef[no_bytes_to_read];
```

Declares a pointer of class Bytef which will point to the array allocated by the new [] operator.

Answer (score 2):

Bytef is defined in the zlib source code.  I downloaded the latest version of zlib when I am typing this message: zlib-1.2.11.  Inside this directory (after unpacking),

```
find . -type f | xargs grep Bytef 
many lines ignored
......
./zconf.h:   typedef Byte  FAR Bytef;
...... 
more lines ignored
```

Note, Byte is not a type in C or C++ although byte is.  So I have to read more lines of code.  FAR is a macro defined in zlib.  The shorter search pattern for grep will result in many more lines. I add a little bit more filters.

```
find . -type f | xargs grep Byte | sed '/Bytef/d' | sed '/test/d' | grep typedef
./ChangeLog:- Correct Macintosh avoidance of typedef Byte in zconf.h
//**This is what you want: 
./zconf.h:typedef unsigned char  Byte;  /* 8 bits */

./zconf.h:   typedef Byte const *voidpc;
./zconf.h:   typedef Byte FAR   *voidpf;
./zconf.h:   typedef Byte       *voidp;
./zconf.h.cmakein:typedef unsigned char  Byte;  /* 8 bits */
./zconf.h.cmakein:   typedef Byte const *voidpc;
./zconf.h.cmakein:   typedef Byte FAR   *voidpf;
./zconf.h.cmakein:   typedef Byte       *voidp;
./zconf.h.in:typedef unsigned char  Byte;  /* 8 bits */
./zconf.h.in:   typedef Byte const *voidpc;
./zconf.h.in:   typedef Byte FAR   *voidpf;
./zconf.h.in:   typedef Byte       *voidp;
```

You can see, C uses a lots of typedefs.  Sometime it is mind spinning.  I am showing this method how to query a source project, so you can figure out the answer for similar type of problems.

FAR is another MACRO defined in zconf.h, but it is not that easy to understand. A lots of def and undef which basically makes FAR as nothing.

When you include zlib.h, new Bytef[10] is the same as new unsinged char[10].  You can even add FAR.  In the example code by the authors of zlib used:

```
unsigned char in[CHUNK];
```

instead of Bytef in[CHUNK].  Here CHUNK is another MACRO. You use a lots of MACROS in C.

Answer (score 1):

You could find this thread useful: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/485109-cpython-compression/

Comment: There might be some useful information there, but there's an awful lot of irrelevant stuff too. Your answer would be *a lot* better if you could distill the pertinent aspects out into your text here rather than just simply linking elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a boost scoped_array for my ByteF buffer to take care of memory clean up.  It is working well

```
boost::scoped_array<Bytef> buf(new unsigned char[ no_bytes_to_read]);
```

When passing this buffer to compress or uncompress make sure to add 'get()' to access the internal raw memory.

```
int ret = compress(buf.get(), ...
```